# Laravel, how to change text if condition is met?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Currently this is the codes in my view.

**in view**

```
<?php $cond = true ?>

<p id="p1">I wanted to change this text if the condition is met</p>
@if($cond)
  //what should i do here to change the text above?
@endif
```

how about to change it to html? like this

```
$text = "<i class='fa fa-times' style='color: red'></i>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that text in some variable, and on condition= true, you can just update the variable's value.
Suppose you have a variable

```
$someText = "I wanted to change this text if the condition is met";
```

And this is your view:

```
<?php $cond = true ?>

@if($cond)
  <?php $someText = "Now I have new text"; ?>
@endif

<p id="p1">{{$someText}}</p>
```

If you want to avoid using temporary variable, you can do like this.

```
@if($cond)
  <p id="p1">Text 1</p>
@else
  <p id="p1">Text2</p>
@endif
```

With the edit in question, as you want to display html as plain-text. You can try this:

```
{!! $text !!}
```

Comment: is there another simpler way to do this? perhaps less memory needed?

Comment: how about to change it to html? like this $text =  "<i class='fa fa-times' style='color: red'></i>";

Comment: I think its simpler, just one variable is required to store text. Do you think it will cost any expensive call on memory ? Or if you don't want to use temp variable then you can simply just update <p> inside the condition, and display text in both if-else blocks.

Comment: sounds good, by the way, i updated my question...do u have any ideas to solve the prob?

Comment: Welcome, Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one is the simple question

```
<p id="p1">{!! $con ? "I wanted to change this text if the condition is met" : "<i class='fa fa-times' style='color: red'></i>" !!}</p>
```